# Joomla 3.1.4 ,JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file,error

Tags: plugins, joomla

I have setup already joomla 3.1.4 and I tried to install a plugin,But Im getting this error:
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

This is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 1.5//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.5/template-install.dtd">
    <extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="content" client="myjoomlasite">
        <name>plg_content_helloworld</name>
        <author>Tahsin Çetin</author>
        <creationDate>July 27th,2013</creationDate>
        <copyright>Tahsin Çetin</copyright>
        <licence>GNU General Public License</licence>
        <authorEmail>tcetin@yandex.com</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>http://tahsincetin.com</authorUrl>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <description>Simple Hello World plugin</description>
        <files>
            <filename plugin="helloworld">helloworld.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>helloworld.xml</filename>
        </files>
    </extension>
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to specify "helloworld.xml" in your xml file.Remove file and install again.This will be your final xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
    <extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="content" client="myjoomlasite">
        <name>plg_content_helloworld</name>
        <author>Tahsin Çetin</author>
        <creationDate>July 27th,2013</creationDate>
        <copyright>Tahsin Çetin</copyright>
        <licence>GNU General Public License</licence>
        <authorEmail>tcetin@yandex.com</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>http://tahsincetin.com</authorUrl>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <description>Simple Hello World plugin</description>
        <files>
            <filename plugin="helloworld">helloworld.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>                
        </files>
    </extension>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The "Cannot find Joomla XML setup file" usually means you are trying to install an extension that wasn't designed for the version of Joomla you are installing to.

Read more [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=764742)

Answer (score 1):

In your opening `<extension>` tag, you do not need to specify a client attribute.

Where is the XML file in relation to your ZIP package?  If it isn't at the top level of the ZIP, it won't be found.

Answer (score -1):

Generally when this happens something is wrong with the XML file.  If you have made any changes, try to think where those changes were and find a problem with the XML file.

Problems could be:

- No opening or closing tag.  Closing tags are easy to miss.  Count them, make sure there's an opening and a closing tag.
- Duplicated tags.  It's easy to add two `labels` or `showons` for example, especially if you are copying and pasting.
- Space before the opening XML tag
- No closing `fieldset` tag
- No closing `extension` or `config` tag.  Easily deleted if you are replacing the file

You can easily use a tool like this:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Which will help you to find issues such as missing opening and closing tags.

Comment: I've deleted all your other exact pasted answers. Please flag as duplicate instead next time

Comment: Ok sure, I'll find out how and do so. Although they weren't all duplicates, some were similar but others may find them by searching the same thing. How would I handle such a situation? Link the question in a comment?

Comment: if they're the same, flag as duplicate with the "flag" button. If it's not, adapt your solution to each question instead of pasting the same over and over.

Comment: There were correct answers there already, that had been accepted as correct, by my answer showed other alternatives.  I think perhaps I'll just edit the correct answer and add it?  Or should I edit the correct answer and add links to the other answers?  One one hand I guess SO encourages points but on the other it's an extra click for users